# A greedy algorithm for converting a binary matrix to zero matrix by flipping the cells

Tags: algorithm, matrix, greedy

We have a M*N matrix with some 1 and 0, we want to make all of these cells zero using a 2*2 square. When this square is pushed on 4 cells their contents will be flopped. We want to find if there is any answer to a given matrix to completely convert all cells to zero or not.

Is there any greedy answer to this?

Comment: So just to make it clear - in each operation you choose a square of 2x2 squares and flip the value of each cell?

Comment: You didn't say how you move 2x2 square. the conversion occurs automatically or by applying it?

Comment: by applying it...and also you are not allowed to move 2x2 square out of larger matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your larger matrix M and your small one ( the 2x2 ) P

Scan your P from left to right, and top to bottom on M. Every time the top left hand of cell of P on M is 1 apply P.

By the time you get to the bottom right part of M every cell except the right hand column and bottom row of M is guaranteed to be 0.

If those last columns are not zero then there is no solution.

You can prove that not every matrix can be cleared by this process. For example if M were a 2x2 non-zero matrix it could never be cleared using this process.

Neither can any matrix M of any size with between 1 and 3 cells set to 1.

I suspect that there is a more general unsolvable case - e.g. it could be that matrices that don't have a multiple of 4 bits set to 1 cannot be solved this way.

Thinking about it more - I don't think you can solve any matrix with an odd number of 1's on any row or column.

Comment: "By the time you get to the bottom right part of the larger matrix every cell except the bottom 2x2 box is guaranteed to be 0." - not true. "For example if M were a 2x2 non-zero matrix it could never be cleared using this process. " - also not true.

Comment: Sorry. everything but the bottom row and last column. Since I assume P cant go outside of M